# Focused TextBox margin in ScrollViewer

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

For example: i have standard Windows Phone app with ApplicationBar (important!) and with this code inside ContentPanel:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Margin="12,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="..." />
            <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

And when TextBox is focuded, there's big margin above keyboard. IT'S NOT THE WORD FLOW.

Look at screenshots:

[image]

When there's no ApplicationBar — there's no any margin. What's problem?

Comment: It's not a margin. It's panel with possible results of user input(like T9). For example, if you copy some text, in this panel will be button for input this text, or if you start typing something in TextBox in this panel must shows possible results. I'm not shure about emulator. Also, you can watch this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh393998(v=vs.105).aspx for details.

Comment: @Catherine it's not possible results. It's margin.